# How can I make a dropdown list to delete not compatible fields?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to make a form that deletes the fields that are not possible as It is filled. I want to make a dropdown list and when ever something is selected deletes other fields.
I'm not getting to run the dropdown part.

I'm new at this but it should be something easy to make. I have a dropdown list in word with different values(0,1,2,3,4) for the different options.

I'm trying to run the code from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.dropdown)

```
ActiveDocument.FormFields("DropDown1").DropDown.Value = 1
```

It gives me:

```
Runtime error '5941': The requested member of the collection does not exist.
```

Possible this is a very basic mistake but I'm spending a lot of time on this and I find it very difficult to find resources for VBA for word. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: is your dropdown list named `"DropDown1"`?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, the name of the dopdown list on word and the code are the same.

Comment: My best guess, from what's in the question, is that the dropdown in the document is not a form field. There are at least three different possibilities, and each uses a different technology (and thus different code). You need to specify exactly what kind of dropdown this is.